# How correctly expose data from PagingSource Paging 3

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-paging-3

Lets say we have a api response:

```
{
  "filters": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Filter1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Filter2"
    }
  ],
  "selected_filter_id": "1",
  "data": [
    {
      "": ""
    },
    {
      "": ""
    },
    {
      "": ""
    },
    {
      "": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

And we want to expose filters separately of data using Paging 3 library, so it will update filters entity every new page requested, we can add liveData to our PagingSource to store filters in it like so:

**PagingSource**

```
private val _filters = MutableLiveData<Filters?>(null)
val filters: LiveData<Filters?> = _filters
```

And then in load function we can update liveData value with filters received from response:

**load()**

```
_filters.value = response.filters
```

Data from response will be exposed by pager as PagingData and submitted to PagingDataAdapter but what the best way to expose filters to UI? So far the only thing that works is to use MediatorLiveData, in ViewModel which creates Pager we have to initialize liveData like this:

**ViewModel:**

```
private val _filters = MediatorLiveData<Filters?>()
val filters: LiveData<Filters?> = _filters
```

And every time we create Pager we can use MediatorLiveData to set value received from PagingSource's liveData:

**ViewModel**

```
var currentPager = Pager(
  config = PagingConfig(params...),
  pagingSourceFactory = {
    DataSource(params...)
      .also {
        _filters.addSource(it.filters) { filters ->
        _filters.value = filters
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Every time we create Pager (we have to create new one each time we apply new filter to request) we also use liveData from DataSource to receive new filters and set them in viewModel's liveData, and then in UI we can observe it like usually:

**UI**

```
viewModel.filters.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { filters ->
  // do something
}
```

This is working approach but it seems to me wrong from architecture's point of view. Is there any better solution?